# Infraction Has Been Already Acknowledged - DiscordAPIError Problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

so I have been working on this **help command** for some time now. In the beginning, there was no such error, but now even after all the methods I came up with, weren't able to fix this error. I tried to remove the **selectMenu** after **60s** to prevent **old interactions to launch** as well but it still doesn't seem to work properly. I have added my code to this as well, please do help me.

```
const { MessageSelectMenu, Collector } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    description: "This is a help command!",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client){
        let commandUser = message.author.id
        let helpEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#EF4344')
            .setAuthor('Builder BOT • Help-Command','https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/960440764737921074/960790159597641758/builder_bot_06.png')
            .setDescription(`• My prefix is \`b!\`.\n • We recommend to give the BOT Administrator permission.\n • We recommend NOT to change the BOT-role's and channel's permission.\n • Type \`b!help <module>\` for further information regarding a specific module.\n • Type \`b!help <command>\` for further information regarding a specific command.`)
            .addFields({
                name: 'BOT-Modules:',
                value: `• <:Hammer:960753810253414401>_Build-Module_\n • <:Gear:960764548195958834>_Config-Module_\n • <:Pencil:960962910463598615>_Action Log-Module_\n • <:Staff:960964396425814117>_Moderation-Module_\n • <:Misc:960964890460319855>_Misc-Module_\n • <:Rocket:960965476673019954>_Fun-Module_`,
                inline: true
            },{
                name: 'BOT-Updates:',
                value: '**Help command under-development**\n Use the command for more information.\n Eg- \`b!help\`',
                inline: true
            })
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(`Author ID: ${message.author.id}`,`${message.author.displayAvatarURL()}`);

        let helpSelectMenu = new Discord.MessageActionRow().addComponents([
            new MessageSelectMenu()
            .setCustomId('Help-SelectMenu')
            .setPlaceholder('For more information, choose a module!')
            .addOptions([
                {
                    label: 'Build-Module',
                    value: 'Build_Option',
                    description: 'Build servers more easily than ever before!',
                    emoji: `<:Hammer:960753810253414401>`
                },
                {
                    label: 'Config-Module',
                    value: 'Config_Option',
                    description: 'Configure Builder BOT\'s settings!',
                    emoji: `<:Gear:960764548195958834>`
                },
                {
                    label: 'Action Log-Module',
                    value: 'Action Log_Option',
                    description: 'Keep track of everything that happens in the server!',
                    emoji: `<:Pencil:960962910463598615>`
                },
                {
                    label: 'Moderation-Module',
                    value: 'Moderation_Option',
                    description: 'Automate moderation and protect your server!',
                    emoji: `<:Staff:960964396425814117>`
                },
                {
                    label: 'Misc-Module',
                    value: 'Misc_Option',
                    description: 'Uncategorized amazing features!',
                    emoji: `<:Misc:960964890460319855>`
                },
                {
                    label: 'Fun-Module',
                    value: 'Fun_Option',
                    description: 'Engage members with interactive commands!',
                    emoji: `<:Rocket:960965476673019954>`
                }
            ])
        ])

        message.channel.send({ embeds: [helpEmbed], components: [helpSelectMenu] }).catch(() => {
            if(message.channel.permissionsFor(client.user.id).has(['SEND_MESSAGES'])){
                message.channel.send(`<@${message.author.id}>, I don't have the required permissions!`).then(msg => {
                    setTimeout(() => {msg.delete()}, 5000)
                })
            }else{
                return;
            };
        }).then((msg) => {
            setTimeout(() => {msg.edit({ embeds: [helpEmbed], components: []})}, 60000)
        });

        let underDevelopment = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#EF4344')
        .setDescription('The BOT is currently under development process!')
        .setTimestamp()

        let helpDropdownfilter = (interaction) => (interaction.isSelectMenu() && interaction.user.id === message.author.id);
        let helpDropdownCollector = message.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
            helpDropdownfilter,
            max: 2,
            time: 60000
        });

        helpDropdownCollector.on('collect', async (interaction) => {
            console.log(interaction.values[0]);
            if(commandUser === interaction.user.id){
                if(interaction.values[0] === 'Build_Option'){
                    underDevelopment.setAuthor('Builder BOT • Build-Module','https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/960440764737921074/960790159597641758/builder_bot_06.png')
                    underDevelopment.setFooter(`Interaction ID: ${interaction.user.id}`,`${interaction.user.displayAvatarURL()}`);
                    await interaction.update({ embeds: [underDevelopment], components: [] });
                }
                if(interaction.values[0] === 'Config_Option'){
                    underDevelopment.setAuthor('Builder BOT • Config-Module','https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/960440764737921074/960790159597641758/builder_bot_06.png')
                    underDevelopment.setFooter(`Interaction ID: ${interaction.user.id}`,`${interaction.user.displayAvatarURL()}`);
                    await interaction.update({ embeds: [underDevelopment], components: []});
                }
                if(interaction.values[0] === 'Action Log_Option'){
                    underDevelopment.setAuthor('Builder BOT • Action Log-Module','https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/960440764737921074/960790159597641758/builder_bot_06.png')
                    underDevelopment.setFooter(`Interaction ID: ${interaction.user.id}`,`${interaction.user.displayAvatarURL()}`);
                    await interaction.update({ embeds: [underDevelopment], components: [] });
                }
                if(interaction.values[0] === 'Moderation_Option'){
                    underDevelopment.setAuthor('Builder BOT • Moderation-Work','https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/960440764737921074/960790159597641758/builder_bot_06.png')
                    underDevelopment.setFooter(`Interaction ID: ${interaction.user.id}`,`${interaction.user.displayAvatarURL()}`);
                    await interaction.update({ embeds: [underDevelopment], components: [] });
                }
                if(interaction.values[0] === 'Misc_Option'){
                    underDevelopment.setAuthor('Builder BOT • Misc-Module','https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/960440764737921074/960790159597641758/builder_bot_06.png')
                    underDevelopment.setFooter(`Interaction ID: ${interaction.user.id}`,`${interaction.user.displayAvatarURL()}`);
                    await interaction.update({ embeds: [underDevelopment], components: [] });
                }
                if(interaction.values[0] === 'Fun_Option'){
                    underDevelopment.setAuthor('Builder BOT • Fun-Module','https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/960440764737921074/960790159597641758/builder_bot_06.png')
                    underDevelopment.setFooter(`Interaction ID: ${interaction.user.id}`,`${interaction.user.displayAvatarURL()}`);
                    await interaction.update({ embeds: [underDevelopment], components: [] });
                }
            }else{
                await interaction.reply({ content: `<@${interaction.user.id}>, you do not have access to this interaction!`, ephemeral: true})
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to keep the flags to prevent other errors cause my perms mismatch

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using a lot of `if` conditions. I'd suggest using `if` and `else if` instead of using `if` multiple times. Also, try the following code;

```js
const initial = await message.channel.send({ /** ... */ });
const filter = // ...
const collector = // ...
collector.on("collect", async(interaction) => {
   if(interaction.values[0] === "something"){
      if(initial.editable){
         await initial.edit(/** ... */)
      } else return;
   } else if (interaction.values[0] === "anything"){
      // ...
   }
})
```

You're basically saving the first response of the bot, to later on edit the responses as they select options from the menu.